# converting sql query to equivalent spark query

Tags: apache-spark, java-8, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am using `spark-sql-2.4.1v` with java8.

I have scenario/snippet like below

```
Dataset<Row> df =//loaded data from a csv file
// this has columns like "code1","code2","code3","code4","code5","code6", and "class"
 
 df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_tab");

List<String> codesList = Arrays.asList("code1","code5"); // codes of interest to be calculated.
 
 codesList.stream().forEach( code -> {
 
 String query = "select " 
                                  + " avg(" + code + ") as mean, "
                                  + "percentile(" + code +",0.25) as p25" 
                                  + "from " + temp_tab                      
                                  + " group by class";
                
  Dataset<Row> resultDs  = sparkSession.sql(query);
 });
```

**how can this be written using functions.expr() & functions.agg() ?**

Comment: Somthing like this ? `df.groupBy("class").agg(avg("code").alias("mean"), percentile("code", 0.25).alias("p25"))`

Comment: @blackbishop there is no function called percentile

Comment: @Costi Ciudatu In the above case , how can I collect resultDs datasets using reduce/map function ?

Comment: you can use it with `expr`: `expr("percentile(code, 0.25)").alias("p25")`

Comment: @blackbishop getting error saying '`code`' given input columns:  ..here i need to get this from codesList i.e.  codesList.stream().forEach( code -> {

Comment: @blackbishop tried  data.groupBy("class").agg( expr("percentile( col(${code}) ), 0.25)").alias("p25")).show  ... still getting  ParseException